# How to center SVG within its container?

Tags: css, svg

How does one center this SVG horizontally within `.svg_wrapper`?

```css
.svg_wrapper {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg_wrapper">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 600 425">
            <path d="M 175, 175 m 0, -75 a 75,75 0 1,0 0,150 a 75,75 0 1,0 0,-150" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="150" stroke-dasharray="0 600 600 0" stroke-dashoffset="1000">
                <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="0" to="600" dur="2s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" />
            </path>
        </svg>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/fj7Xc/

Tried stuff like `margin: 0 auto`, `text-align: center` as well as flexbox but to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SVG is centered in the wrapper...the path, however, is not centered in the SVG

You would have to adjust the `viewbox` accordingly

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 350 350">
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fj7Xc/1/)

Comment: can you please explain how does that work?